Selenium Grid 4.20.0-20240505: WebSocketHandshakeException and 'Driver version unknown' Error When Running Tests on Container Selenium Grid
I'm facing an issue while running tests on a Selenium Grid (version 4.20.0-20240505) that I've deployed using a Helm chart. My setup includes the following:

Selenium Grid Version: 4.20.0-20240505

Helm Chart Version: 0.30.1

Browser Nodes: Chrome and Edge

Environment: Kubernetes

Access: Grid console via Node IP and Node Port

Logging: Attempting to mount logs to Azure Storage (not yet done)
The helm chart I'm using is Selenium grid helm chart 0.30.1 - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/charts/selenium-grid/CHANGELOG.md#heavy_check_mark-selenium-grid-0300
The images I'm using are - selenium/node-chrome:4.20.0-20240505 and selenium/hub:4.20.0-20240505
I tried to retrieve DockerFile from the image NodeChrome I'm using  -
ARG RELEASE
ARG LAUNCHPAD_BUILD_ARCH
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.ref.name=ubuntu
LABEL org.opencontainers.image.version=22.04
ADD file:a5d32dc2ab15ff0d7dbd72af26e361eb1f3e87a0d29ec3a1ceab24ad7b3e6ba9 in /
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
LABEL authors=Selenium <selenium-developers@googlegroups.com> 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG VERSION 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG RELEASE=selenium-4.20.0 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG AUTHORS=SeleniumHQ 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG OPENTELEMETRY_VERSION=1.36.0 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG GRPC_VERSION=1.62.2 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG SEL_USER=seluser 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG SEL_GROUP=seluser 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG SEL_PASSWD=secret 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG UID=1200 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG GID=1201 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG TZ=UTC 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG JRE_VERSION=17 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG TARGETARCH 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG TARGETVARIANT 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
USER root 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true SEL_USER=seluser SEL_UID=1200 SEL_GID=1201 HOME=/home/seluser TZ=UTC SEL_DOWNLOAD_DIR=/Downloads 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |14 VERSION=4.20.0 RELEASE=selenium-4.20.0 AUTHORS=SeleniumHQ OPENTELEMETRY_VERSION=1.36.0 GRPC_VERSION=1.62.2 SEL_USER=seluser SEL_GROUP=seluser SEL_PASSWD=secret UID=1200 GID=1201 TZ=UTC JRE_VERSION=17 TARGETARCH=amd64 TARGETVARIANT= /bin/sh -c if [ "${TARGETARCH}" = "amd64" ]; then echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe\n" > /etc/apt/sources.list
   &&  echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main universe\n" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   &&  echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main universe\n" >> /etc/apt/sources.list ; fi
   &&  apt-get -qqy update
   &&  apt-get upgrade -yq
   &&  apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install acl bzip2 ca-certificates tzdata sudo unzip wget jq curl supervisor gnupg2 libnss3-tools
   &&  mkdir -p /etc/apt/keyrings
   &&  apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys 843C48A565F8F04B || apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 843C48A565F8F
   &&  wget -qO - https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.asc >dev/null
   &&  echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/adoptium.asc] https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb $(awk -F= '/^VERSION_CODENAME/{print$2}' /etc/os-release) main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list >dev/null
   &&  apt-get -qqy update
   &&  apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install temurin-${JRE_VERSION}-jre -y
   &&  if [ "${TARGETARCH}" = "arm" ]
   &&  [ "${TARGETVARIANT}" = "v7" ]; then export ARCH=armhf ; else export ARCH=${TARGETARCH} ; fi
   &&  sed -i 's/securerandom\.source=file:\/dev\/random/securerandom\.source=file:\/dev\/urandom/' ./usr/lib/jvm/temurin-${JRE_VERSION}-jre-${ARCH}/conf/security/java.security
   &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*
   &&  ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/${TZ} /etc/localtime
   &&  dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata
   &&  cat /etc/timezone
   &&  groupadd ${SEL_GROUP} --gid ${SEL_GID}
   &&  useradd ${SEL_USER} --create-home --gid ${SEL_GID} --shell /bin/bash --uid ${SEL_UID}
   &&  usermod -a -G sudo ${SEL_USER}
   &&  echo 'ALL ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
   &&  echo "${SEL_USER}:${SEL_PASSWD}" | chpasswd
   &&  mkdir -p /opt/selenium /opt/selenium/assets /var/run/supervisor /var/log/supervisor ${SEL_DOWNLOAD_DIR} ${HOME}/.mozilla ${HOME}/.vnc $HOME/.pki/nssdb
   &&  certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -N --empty-password
   &&  touch /opt/selenium/config.toml
   &&  chown -R ${SEL_USER}:${SEL_GROUP} /opt/selenium /var/run/supervisor /var/log/supervisor /etc/passwd ${HOME}
   &&  chmod -R 775 /opt/selenium /var/run/supervisor /var/log/supervisor /etc/passwd ${HOME}
   &&  wget --no-verbose https://github.com/${AUTHORS}/selenium/releases/download/${RELEASE}/selenium-server-${VERSION}.jar -O /opt/selenium/selenium-server.jar
   &&  echo "${SEL_PASSWD}" > /opt/selenium/initialPasswd
   &&  chgrp -R 0 /opt/selenium ${HOME} /opt/selenium/assets /var/run/supervisor /var/log/supervisor
   &&  chmod -R g=u /opt/selenium ${HOME} /opt/selenium/assets /var/run/supervisor /var/log/supervisor
   &&  setfacl -Rm u:${SEL_USER}:rwx /opt /opt/selenium ${HOME} /opt/selenium/assets /var/run/supervisor /var/log/supervisor
   &&  setfacl -Rm g:${SEL_GROUP}:rwx /opt /opt/selenium ${HOME} /opt/selenium/assets /var/run/supervisor /var/log/supervisor
   &&  if [ `arch` = "aarch64" ] || [ `arch` = "x86_64" ]; then curl -fL https://github.com/coursier/launchers/raw/master/cs-`arch`-pc-linux.gz | gzip -d > /tmp/cs
   &&  chmod +x /tmp/cs
   &&  mkdir -p /external_jars
   &&  chmod -R 775 /external_jars ; fi
   &&  if [ -f "/tmp/cs" ]; then /tmp/cs fetch --classpath --cache /external_jars io.opentelemetry:opentelemetry-exporter-otlp:${OPENTELEMETRY_VERSION} io.grpc:grpc-netty:${GRPC_VERSION} > /external_jars/.classpath.txt ; fi
   &&  chmod 664 /external_jars/.classpath.txt
   &&  rm -fr /root/.cache/*
   &&  echo 'if [[ $(ulimit -n) -gt 200000 ]]; then echo "WARNING: Very high value reported by \"ulimit -n\". Consider passing \"--ulimit nofile=32768\" to \"docker run\"."; fi' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc # buildkit 327MB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY check-grid.sh entry_point.sh /opt/bin/ # buildkit 1.27kB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY supervisord.conf /etc # buildkit 1.5kB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
USER 1200:1201 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ENV SE_BIND_HOST=false SE_REJECT_UNSUPPORTED_CAPS=false SE_OTEL_JAVA_GLOBAL_AUTOCONFIGURE_ENABLED=true SE_OTEL_TRACES_EXPORTER=otlp 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
CMD ["/opt/bin/entry_point.sh"] 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
LABEL authors= 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG NOVNC_SOURCE=heads 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG NOVNC_VERSION=master 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG WEBSOCKIFY_SOURCE=heads 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG WEBSOCKIFY_VERSION=master 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG LANG_WHICH=en 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG LANG_WHERE=US 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG ENCODING=UTF-8 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG TARGETARCH 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
USER root 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ENV LANG_WHICH=en LANG_WHERE=US ENCODING=UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 LANG= SE_ENABLE_BROWSER_LEFTOVERS_CLEANUP=false SE_BROWSER_LEFTOVERS_INTERVAL_SECS=3600 SE_BROWSER_LEFTOVERS_PROCESSES_SECS=7200 SE_BROWSER_LEFTOVERS_TEMPFILES_DAYS=1 SE_DRAIN_AFTER_SESSION_COUNT=0 SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=1 SE_NODE_SESSION_TIMEOUT=300 SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=false SE_NODE_HEARTBEAT_PERIOD=30 SE_OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=selenium-node SE_OFFLINE=true SE_SCREEN_WIDTH=1360 SE_SCREEN_HEIGHT=1020 SE_SCREEN_DEPTH=24 SE_SCREEN_DPI=96 SE_START_XVFB=true SE_START_VNC=true SE_START_NO_VNC=true SE_NO_VNC_PORT=7900 SE_VNC_PORT=5900 DISPLAY=:99.0 DISPLAY_NUM=99 CONFIG_FILE=/opt/selenium/config.toml GENERATE_CONFIG=true DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |8 NOVNC_SOURCE=heads NOVNC_VERSION=master WEBSOCKIFY_SOURCE=heads WEBSOCKIFY_VERSION=master LANG_WHICH=en LANG_WHERE=US ENCODING=UTF-8 TARGETARCH=amd64 /bin/sh -c apt-get update -qqy
   &&  apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install xvfb libxcb1 xauth pulseaudio x11vnc x11-utils fluxbox eterm hsetroot feh locales libfontconfig libfreetype6 xfonts-scalable fonts-liberation fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-tlwg-loma-otf fonts-noto-color-emoji
   &&  locale-gen ${LANGUAGE}
   &&  dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive locales
   &&  if [ "${TARGETARCH}" = "amd64" ]; then apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install language-pack-en xfonts-cyrillic fonts-ubuntu ; fi
   &&  apt-get -qyy autoremove
   &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   &&  apt-get -qyy clean
   &&  wget -nv -O noVNC.zip "https://github.com/novnc/noVNC/archive/refs/${NOVNC_SOURCE}/${NOVNC_VERSION}.zip"
   &&  unzip -x noVNC.zip
   &&  mv noVNC-${NOVNC_VERSION} /opt/bin/noVNC
   &&  cp /opt/bin/noVNC/vnc.html /opt/bin/noVNC/index.html
   &&  rm noVNC.zip
   &&  wget -nv -O websockify.zip "https://github.com/novnc/websockify/archive/refs/${WEBSOCKIFY_SOURCE}/${WEBSOCKIFY_VERSION}.zip"
   &&  unzip -x websockify.zip
   &&  rm websockify.zip
   &&  mv websockify-${WEBSOCKIFY_VERSION} /opt/bin/noVNC/utils/websockify
   &&  rm -rf /opt/bin/noVNC/utils/websockify/docker /opt/bin/noVNC/utils/websockify/tests
   &&  chmod +x /dev/shm
   &&  mkdir -p /tmp/.X11-unix
   &&  x11vnc -storepasswd $(cat /opt/selenium/initialPasswd) ${HOME}/.vnc/passwd
   &&  chown -R "${SEL_USER}:${SEL_GROUP}" ${HOME}/.vnc
   &&  chmod -R 775 ${HOME} /tmp/.X11-unix
   &&  chgrp -R 0 ${HOME} /tmp/.X11-unix
   &&  chmod -R g=u ${HOME} /tmp/.X11-unix # buildkit 354MB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY start-selenium-node.sh start-xvfb.sh start-vnc.sh start-novnc.sh generate_config /opt/bin/ # buildkit 12.2kB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY selenium_grid_logo.png /usr/share/images/fluxbox/ubuntu-light.png # buildkit 20.4kB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY selenium.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ # buildkit 1.73kB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
USER 1200 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
EXPOSE map[5900/tcp:{}] 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
LABEL authors= 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
USER root 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG TARGETARCH 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |2 CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable TARGETARCH=amd64 /bin/sh -c wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/google.gpg >/dev/null
   &&  echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   &&  apt-get update -qqy
   &&  if echo "${CHROME_VERSION}" | grep -qE "google-chrome-stable[_|=][0-9]*"; then CHROME_VERSION=$(echo "$CHROME_VERSION" | tr '=' '_')
   &&  wget -qO google-chrome.deb "https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/${CHROME_VERSION}_${TARGETARCH}.deb"
   &&  apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install --allow-downgrades ./google-chrome.deb
   &&  rm -rf google-chrome.deb ; else apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install ${CHROME_VERSION} ; fi
   &&  rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
   &&  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/* # buildkit 413MB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY wrap_chrome_binary /opt/bin/wrap_chrome_binary # buildkit 712B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |2 CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable TARGETARCH=amd64 /bin/sh -c /opt/bin/wrap_chrome_binary # buildkit 2.4kB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ARG CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |3 CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable TARGETARCH=amd64 CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION= /bin/sh -c if [ ! -z "$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION" ]; then CHROME_DRIVER_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip ; else CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION=$(google-chrome --version | sed -E "s/.* ([0-9]+)(\.[0-9]+){3}.*/\1/")
   &&  echo "Geting ChromeDriver latest version from https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION}"
   &&  CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=$(wget -qO- https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_${CHROME_MAJOR_VERSION} | sed 's/\r$//')
   &&  CHROME_DRIVER_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip ; fi
   &&  echo "Using ChromeDriver from: "$CHROME_DRIVER_URL
   &&  echo "Using ChromeDriver version: "$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
   &&  wget --no-verbose -O /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip $CHROME_DRIVER_URL
   &&  rm -rf /opt/selenium/chromedriver
   &&  unzip /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/selenium
   &&  rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip
   &&  mv /opt/selenium/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
   &&  chmod 755 /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION
   &&  ln -fs /opt/selenium/chromedriver-$CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION /usr/bin/chromedriver # buildkit 16.7MB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY chrome-cleanup.sh /opt/bin/chrome-cleanup.sh # buildkit 1.36kB buildkit.dockerfile.v0
COPY chrome-cleanup.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/chrome-cleanup.conf # buildkit 775B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
USER 1200 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |3 CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable TARGETARCH=amd64 CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION= /bin/sh -c echo "chrome" > /opt/selenium/browser_name # buildkit 7B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |3 CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable TARGETARCH=amd64 CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION= /bin/sh -c google-chrome --version | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d'.' -f1,2 > /opt/selenium/browser_version # buildkit 6B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
RUN |3 CHROME_VERSION=google-chrome-stable TARGETARCH=amd64 CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION= /bin/sh -c echo "\"goog:chromeOptions\": {\"binary\": \"/usr/bin/google-chrome\"}" > /opt/selenium/browser_binary_location # buildkit 59B buildkit.dockerfile.v0
ENV SE_OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=selenium-node-chrome 0B buildkit.dockerfile.v0



Problem:
I'm trying to run app tests on a non-SSL Selenium Grid container for the Chrome browser. However, the tests are failing with the following errors:

Error: Driver version unknown

Caused by: java.net.http.WebSocketHandshakeException

Caused by: jdk.internal.net.http.WebSocket.CheckFailedException

HTTP Response: Unexpected status code 404
I have set up a jenkins deployment job that helps me run the tests.
Error code in jenkins console -
Build info: version: '4.20.0', revision: '866c76ca80'
19:58:43  System info: os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.7'
19:58:43  Driver info: driver.version: unknown
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.openSocket(JdkHttpClient.java:243)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.(Connection.java:87)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.SeleniumCdpConnection.(SeleniumCdpConnection.java:36)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.SeleniumCdpConnection.lambda$create$3(SeleniumCdpConnection.java:103)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:260)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.SeleniumCdpConnection.create(SeleniumCdpConnection.java:103)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.SeleniumCdpConnection.create(SeleniumCdpConnection.java:49)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsProvider.getImplementation(DevToolsProvider.java:50)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevToolsProvider.getImplementation(DevToolsProvider.java:29)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter.augment(Augmenter.java:207)
19:58:43    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.Augmenter.augment(Augmenter.java:178)
19:58:43    at com.qa.trizetto.core.SeleniumMain.getAugmentedDriver(SeleniumMain.java:367)
19:58:43    at com.qa.trizetto.core.SeleniumMain.setDriver(SeleniumMain.java:372)
19:58:43    at com.qa.trizetto.core.SeleniumMain.(SeleniumMain.java:134)
19:58:43    at com.qa.trizetto.core.SeleniumMain.getInstance(SeleniumMain.java:118)
19:58:43    at com.qa.trizetto.core.SeleniumMain.getInstance(SeleniumMain.java:79)
19:58:43    at com.qa.trizetto.core.BaseTest.afterClass(BaseTest.java:162)
19:58:43    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19:58:43    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
19:58:43    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
19:58:43    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
19:58:43    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
19:58:43    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
19:58:43    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
19:58:43    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
19:58:43    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeAfterClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:214)
19:58:43    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
19:58:43  Caused by: java.net.http.WebSocketHandshakeException
19:58:43    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.resultFrom(OpeningHandshake.java:226)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1150)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:614)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:844)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:483)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
19:58:43    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
19:58:43  Caused by: jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.CheckFailedException: Unexpected HTTP response status code 404
19:58:43    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.checkFailed(OpeningHandshake.java:343)
19:58:43    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.handleResponse(OpeningHandshake.java:252)
19:58:43    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.resultFrom(OpeningHandshake.java:222)
19:58:43    ... 10 more


What I've Tried:

Browsers: Tested with different versions of Chrome and Edge.
Applications: Attempted both SSL and non-SSL apps, as well as Windows apps and containerized apps.
WebSocket Configuration: Reviewed the Helm chart but unsure of the necessary WebSocket configurations in values.yaml.
Logging: Looking to configure Selenium Grid logs to be generated/mounted in Azure Storage, but I haven't found a clear method in the current Helm chart setup.

Request:

WebSocket Configuration: What should I add in the values.yaml for WebSocket support in Selenium Grid?
Error Resolution: How can I resolve the Driver version unknown error, and what might be causing the WebSocketHandshakeException and CheckFailedException errors?
Logging Setup: How can I properly configure Selenium Grid logs to be stored in Azure Storage via the Helm chart?

